# Python requests directory relative to script directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Trying my first steps at webscraping and following a simple tutorial.

Python is installed at  "C:/users/username/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32" (I didnt choose this directory).

Requests is definitely installed.

The script i am running is in "C:/Python"

The full and complete code I am running is

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/simple.html")
```

Error message i am getting

```
File C:\Python\requests.py, line 1   pip install requests
        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which seems to me like it thinks the Requests code is in the same directory as my script. Which it isn't. It's outputting code in the error that is not in the code I entered. Am I right and how do i fix it? Thanks for all assistance!

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: I get the same error whether i run in cmd line or in atom via `script` package

Comment: What is your script called? Show how you run it from the command line. Show the result of running `where python` from the command line.

Comment: (1) Please note that `pip install requests` should be a _command_ you run from command line, not the _content_ of `requests.py`. (2) It's vise to always use [a virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) and don't install packages into your main Python installation.

Comment: The error message clearly shows that `requests.py` contains text which is not even Python code. You need to rename this file so that `import requests` imports the library, not this random file. (Also, including the full traceback would  have made this easier to diagnose.)

Comment: @Mad Physicist - C:\python>where python
C:\Users\thega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\thega\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run below commands in cmd to check installation:

```
python --version
pip show requests
```

If these work fine, run below commands in cmd:

```
python
import requests
page = requests.get(url="http://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/simple.html")
page.content
```

Comment: that worked thank you! I think there's something funky in my setup as it works in cmd but nowhere else. That's my next job i guess. But thank you!

Comment: in case this ever helps anyone else i'll add that to fix this i ran the python.exe from the install folder and now everything works as you would want. previously i had just ran a cmd line then typed `python` in which for whatever reason doesnt work...